# Avoid dividing decades in 4 equal parts (0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10)

Tags: matplotlib

Sometimes pyplot divides decades on the axes into 4 equal parts, resulting in ticks at e.g. 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5... E.g. the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [-2, 5, 7, 16] 
y = [0, 3, 7, 19]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.grid()
fig.savefig('fig.png')
```

produces the following figure:

[image]

I find it not useful in majority of cases, in particular when presenting integer numbers. Is there a way to prevent it, that is to allow dividing decades only into 10 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 5 (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10), or 2 (0, 5, 10) equal parts, without adjusting ticks for every single plot manually?

Comment: `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))`